# Simultaneous NonlinearModelFit for two data sets that are separate functions of x and t

Tags: fitting, nonlinear

I am trying to simultaneously fit two data sets that are separate functions of $x$ and $t$ with `NonlinearModelFit`.

Here is an example of the data:

```
datax = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}};
datat = {{1, 4}, {2, 7}, {3, 10}, {4, 13}};
```

Here is an example of models:

```
modelx[a_,b_,x_]:=a*x+b;
modelt[a_,b_,t_]:=a*t+b;
```

The parameters `a` and `b` are shared across the two models.

Here is an example of the code I'd hoped to use:

```
ResourceFunction["MultiNonlinearModelFit"][Join[{datax, datat}],
 {modelx[a, b, x], modelt[a, b, t]}, {a, b}, {x, t}];
```

The resulting error message is:

> NonlinearModelFit: Number of coordinates (2) is not equal to the number of variables (3).

**Edit**

Consider the two data sets below. The first is a decaying exponential, the second is a polynomial. The first is a function of time, the second is a function of position.

```
nPoints = 256;
noiseLevel = 10^-1.5;

dataDecay = Table[{t, Sin[2 \[Pi] 1.0 t] Exp[-0.5 t] + RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, noiseLevel]]}, {t, 0, 10, 10/nPoints}] // Chop;

dataPolys = Table[{x, 1 + (1.0 x^2 + 0.5 x)/100 + RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, noiseLevel]]}, {x, 0, 10, 10/nPoints}] // Chop;
```

I would like to create data sets that indicate whether the data belong to time or position:

```
dataDec = ArrayFlatten[{{Transpose[{ConstantArray[1, Length[dataDecay]]}], dataDecay}}];
dataPol = ArrayFlatten[{{Transpose[{ConstantArray[2, Length[dataPolys]]}], dataPolys}}];
```

I then model the data with the functions that created them:

```
modelDec[a_, b_, t_] := Sin[2 \[Pi] a t] Exp[-b t];
modelPol[a_, b_, x_] := 1 + (a x^2 + b x)/100;
```

So, in theory, when fitting the data, a should come out near 1 and b should come out near 0.5.

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[Join[dataDec, dataPol], {modelDec[a, b, t] + modelPol[a, b, x]}, {{a, 1.0}, {b, 0.5}}, {t, x}, MaxIterations -> Infinity];
```

However, the results are far from this:

```
In[84]:= fit["BestFitParameters"]
```

Out[84]= {a -> 0.743405, b -> -0.203007}

Comment: I don't really understand your distinction between $x$ and $t$. You can rename one of them to the other one: `ResourceFunction["MultiNonlinearModelFit"][Join[{datax, datat}], {modelx[a, b, x], modelt[a, b, x]}, {a, b}, {x}]` Also, are you sure you actually want $a$ and $b$ to be the same in both models? Plotting your data, this clearly isn't the case ...

Comment: Thank you for your comments. You are certainly correct. I tried to simplify the problem at hand, but clearly went too far. I have edited my question to (hopefully) give a better idea of what I'd like to achieve.

Comment: @sje1g13 You still try to fit using two different independent variables. You need to stick with just `x` or just `t`. Also: why are you adding the models together?

Comment: `RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, noiseLevel]]` seems to be an odd construction.  Might you want `RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, noiseLevel]]`.

Comment: The better approach is to use `MultiNonlinearModelFit` as @Domen suggests.  But to make your code work try `fit = NonlinearModelFit[Join[dataDec, dataPol], If[i == 1, modelDec[a, b, x], modelPol[a, b, x]], {{a, 1.0}, {b, 0.5}}, {i, x}, MaxIterations -> Infinity];`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you want to fit 2 function simultaneously. Unfortunately, there is no fit function that can fit vector valued functions. Therefore, you need to "roll your own". You may achieve this by defining a function that calculates the sum of the squared errors and minimize this function.

Here is how you proceed:

The data:

```
nPoints = 256;
noiseLevel = 10^-1.5;

dataDecay = 
  Table[{t, 
     Sin[2 \[Pi] 1.0 t] Exp[-0.5 t] + 
      0 RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, noiseLevel]]}, {t, 0, 10, 
     10/nPoints}] // Chop;

dataPolys = 
  Table[{x, 
     1 + (1.0 x^2 + 0.5 x)/100 + 
      0 RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, noiseLevel]]}, {x, 0, 10, 
     10/nPoints}] // Chop;
```

The models:

```
modelDec[a_, b_, t_] := Sin[2 \[Pi] a t] Exp[-b t];
modelPol[a_, b_, x_] := 1 + (a x^2 + b x)/100;
```

The error function:

```
err[a_, b_] = 
  Total[(modelDec[a, b, #] & /@ dataDecay[[All, 1]] - 
       dataDecay[[All, 2]])^2 + (modelPol[a, b, #] & /@ 
        dataPolys[[All, 1]] - dataPolys[[All, 2]])^2];
```

And the minimization:

```
NMinimize[err[a, b], {a, b}]

{0.533559, {a -> 1.00172, b -> 0.503512}}
```